# How do I manage development and deployment of my website as part of a group?

Tags: php, mysql, svn, deployment

I've been reading this site here and there and appears as though you guys have a wonderful community.

As for my background, I am a sophomore at university familiar with SQL, C++, Visual Basic, and some PHP. One of my school projects for the summer term involves building a web application that allows users to log in and schedule specific timeslots over the internet. Typically, I have been the only person working on a project, but in this case I will be part of a group. Since we're all relatively new to working as a team, I would like to set up source control for my group so we're not all working off a shared drive somewhere. Additionally, I would like to make sure that all of us are able to test our changes in some sort of development server that hosts an instance of our website.

My actual question is in regards to the toolset that we should use to achieve this. As a group, we are most familiar with PHP and MySQL so we'll end up using that for the code and database. I have used SVN in the past for my own personal use, but my group members aren't very familiar with source control. We'll probably stick with something simple like Excel for the project management and bug tracking side of things. Ideally, we would like the tools to be free and open source.

How as a group should we manage the construction of the actual application? Are there methods out there that I can use that will allow any one of us to move the files to our development machine and keep track of who did it so we don't end up overwriting each other's changes? If this is not possible, one of us will write some scripts to handle it - but I would like to avoid building basically a separate software application that will only be used to manage our project. Another issue I foresee will be updating the database running on the development machine. Are there any standardised methods that we can use to manage our SQL scripts among the four of us?

I do not expect a really long winded answer here (after all, this is *our* project!), but any helpful tips would be greatly appreciated. Once I return from holiday I am looking forward to getting started! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend your group use source control to synchronize your code. You can either setup your own server or just use a free provider such as [github](https://github.com/), [Google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/), or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

If you do decide to use one of these sites, a nice feature is that they provide free issue tracking as well, so you can use that instead of Excel.

The best way to manage the SQL scripts is to break them out into separate files and place them under source control as well. You can either create `.sql` files, or use a tool to manage these changes - for example, have a look at [Ruby on Rails' Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). This may take some effort to setup, but you'll thank yourself later if you are working on a project of any size...

Answer (score 2):

1. Draw up a plan for how you would do it if it were just you.
2. Split the plan up into tasks that take around 3-4 hours to complete. Make sure each task has a measurable objective.
3. Divy out the tasks. Try to sort them if possible to maximize developer efficiency.
4. Teach them to use source control. Explain to them that they will use this (maybe not svn, but SOMETHING) in a few years, so they might as well learn how now. Additionally, this will help in every group project they do down the road.
5. Make a script for building and running your tests. Also script your deployment. This will ensure you have the same mechanism going to live as you do going to test, which increases the number of defects found in testing. (This is as opposed to letting them exist but not found in testing.)
6. You mentioned updating the development database. It would be entirely reasonable to dump the development database often with a refresh from live. You may want to make 3 environments. Development, staging, and production. The development database would contain fabricated test data. The staging database would have a copy of live (recent to within a few days maybe.) And of course live is live.
7. Excel works fine as a "bug database." Consider putting it in source control that you manipulate and commit. This will give you a good idea of what happened over time, and you can correct mistakes quicker.

Comment: I just realized... this list looks surprisingly similar to the Joel Test.

Answer (score 2):

As far as source/version control, I would recommend subversion. There are some GUI tools they might use, or even webDAV to access the SVN. This will allow users to edit files collaboratively and also give you details as to who edited what, when, and why... SVN will also do a pretty good job at merging files that happen to be saved at the same time.

It's not the easiest concept to wrap your head around, but its not very complicated once you get running.

I suggest having everyone read the first chapter from: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/

and they should have a good idea of what's happening.

I am also curious to see what people have to say about the database

Answer (score 0):

> How as a group should we manage the construction of the actual application? Are there methods out there that I can use that will allow any one of us to move the files to our development machine and keep track of who did it so we don't end up overwriting each other's changes?

It sounds like you're looking for [build management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build). In the case of PHP, a true "build" is as simple as a collection of source files because the language is interpreted; there is no compilation.

It just so happens that I am one of the developers for [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster), a tool which basically solves every problem you have listed in your question... and it also sounds like it would be free in your case under the Community Edition license. I'll try to address some of your individual pain points and how BuildMaster could be used as a solution.

#### Source Control

As suggested by others, you must use it. The trick when it comes to deployment is to set up some form of [continuous integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) so that every time someone checks in, a new "build" is created. In BuildMaster, you can set this up for any source control provider you want.

#### Issue/Bug Tracking

Excel will work, but it's not an optimal solution. There are plenty of free issue tracking tools you can use to manage your bugs and features. With BuildMaster, you can link your bugs and features list with the application by their release number so you could view them within the tool at any time. It can also modify issue statuses and add descriptions automatically if you want.

#### Deployments

Using BuildMaster, you can create automated deployment plans for your development environment, e.g.:

1. Get Latest Source Code
2. Create Artifact
3. Copy Files To Development Machine
4. Deploy Configuration Files
5. Update Database

The best part is, once you set these up for *other* environments (glowcoder's point #6), pushing all of your code and database updates is as simple as clicking a button.

> Another issue I foresee will be updating the database running on the development machine. Are there any standardised methods that we can use to manage our SQL scripts among the four of us?

#### Database Updates

Not surprisingly, BuildMaster handles these as well by using the change scripts module. When a member of your team creates a script (e.g. `ALTER TABLE ADD [Blah] INT NOT NULL`) he can upload it into BuildMaster, then run it on any environment you have created.

The best part is that you can add a step in your automated deployment and never worry about it again. As Justin mentions, you can use `.sql` files for your object code (stored procedures, views, triggers, etc.) and have those executed on every build since they are essentially code anyway. You can keep those in source control.

#### Configuration Files

One aspect of all this you may have neglected (but will inevitably run into) is dealing with configuration files. With PHP, you may have an .htaccess file, a php.ini file, a prepend.php, or roll your own custom config file. Since by definition configuration files need to change between your personal machine and the development machine, grabbing them from source control wouldn't necessary work without some bit of hacking a la:

```
if (DEV) {
    // do one thing
}
else if (PROD) {
    // do another
}
```

With BuildMaster, you can templatize your configuration files and associate them with an environment so they can be deployed automatically. It will also maintain a history of changes for you.

#### Automated Testing

If you want the full ALM effect, you can automatically unit test your code during an automated build, and notify you if anything fails so you know as soon as possible that something is broken.

---

Apologies for the "long winded" response, but I feel like you're already ahead of the game by observing the problems you might run into in the future and really believe BuildMaster will make all of this deployment stuff simple for your team so you can focus on the fun part, coding!